# Knockout-Kendo RadialGauge pointer transition not working

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz, knockout-kendo

Can anyone explain why this

js:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
   this.myValue = ko.observable(25);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

html:

```
<div data-bind="kendoRadialGauge: myValue"> </div>
```

will allow the pointer to transition nicely to the new value, when the databound value changes.

However when passing additional options, like this

js:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
this.myValue = ko.observable(25);

//various gauge settings omitted for brevity

this.pointerOptions = ko.computed(function() {
       return { color: this.pointerColor(), value: this.myValue() };
   }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel())
```

html:

```
<div data-bind="kendoRadialGauge: { value: myValue, gaugeArea: gaugeOptions, pointer: pointerOptions }"> </div>
```

...the pointer just jumps immediately to the new value.

Knockout 2.3.0, JQuery 2.0.3, Kendo UI Dataviz 2013.2.716

Comment: When you are specifying any of the KO "tracked" options (gaugeArea, pointer, scale) the gauge gets re-drawn by KO with the redwaw method. In itself it shouldn't cause the lost of the transition but KO also slightly changes the gauge's value with  `this.value(0.001 + this.value());` [source](https://github.com/kendo-labs/knockout-kendo/blob/master/src/knockout-kendo-core.js#L272) which causes the transition lost (removing this line fixes your problem). I don't know why this value change was needed maybe kendo also changed since the Datawiz support was added in kendo-knockout a year ago.

Comment: Yep removing the line you said fixes my problem. You can add your comment as the answer if you want and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are specifying any of the KO "tracked" options (`gaugeArea`, `pointe`r, `scale`) the gauge gets re-drawn by KO with using the Kendo's [`redraw` method](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/radialgauge#methods-redraw).

In itself it shouldn't cause the lost of the transition but KO also slightly changes the gauge's value which causes the transition lost.

Source on [github](https://github.com/kendo-labs/knockout-kendo/blob/master/src/knockout-kendo-core.js#L272):

```
this.value(0.001 + this.value());
```

Removing this line from the source code fixes your problem, so I would say this is bug in Knockout-Kendo.